# How to click or select the correct javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am at my wits end.  First let me start I am a total newb to JavaScript and am self learning.

I am trying to ask these questions:

- Click the Shape in the Title
- Then display a series of shapes

How can I show an array of shapes and click on the correct shape in the title?
I also want to store this and give it a point for each correct shape selected.

Here is my jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/arevee/04y7zx0d/

```
var shapeName = ["Square", "Rectangle"];
// Random Shape to Select Title
var shapesTitle = shapeName[Math.floor(Math.random() * shapeName.length)];
document.getElementById("IdShapeTitle").innerHTML = shapesTitle.toString();


var varSquare = document.getElementById("square");
var varRect = document.getElementById("rect");


varSquare.onclick = function () {
    alert("I am square");
};


varRect.onclick = function () {
    alert("I am rectangle");
};

document.getElementById("currentName").innerHTML = shapesTitle.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var MAX_WIDTH = 100;
var MAX_HEIGHT = 100;

// Object oriented way to write JavaScript
var Shape = function(width, height, title) {
    this.width = width,
    this.height = height,
    this.title = title;
}

Shape.prototype.showTitle = function() {
    alert("I am " + this.title);
}

var Rectangle = function(width, height) {
    // if it's a Rectangle with the same width and height return a Square
    if (width === height) return new Square(width);
    // this makes Rectangle a child of Shape
    Shape.call(this, width, height, "Rectangle"),
}

var Square = function(dimension) {
    // this makes Square a child of Shape
    Shape.call(this, dimension, dimension, "Square");
}


// now we make a set amount of Shapes
var shapes = new Array();
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    var w = Math.floor(Math.random() * MAX_WIDTH);
    var h = Math.floor(Math.random() * MAX_HEIGHT);
    shapes.push(new Rectangle(w, h));
}

for (var i = 0; i < shapes.length; i++) {
    console.log(shapes[i].showTitle());
}
```

I think this is the thing you are looking for. Hope this helps and answers your question.

Comment: The alert is not coming up.  I cleaned up the code but still get an error.

Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function:
console.log(shapes[i].showTitle());

http://jsfiddle.net/arevee/uhbnz9od/3/

Comment: How can I correct this error because it is not doing the pseudocode I am wanting.